# Dictionary value is not changed inside a for loop assignment

Tags: python, dictionary

So I am learning python using Learn python the hard way.  I am trying to develop a inventory system.  The goal is to build this into a class that will be pulled by the room class.  I am going to use a dictionary for the inventory so that when I create the inventory for each room I can say where they are in the room.

So in the bedroom I can say that there is a knife on the bed rather than just saying you see knife, candle, oil.

Right now I am working on picking up the item when someone says take knife.  I am able to do a weird search and set that value to None so that when someone looks in the room it does not show up but I seem to be running into a scope issue.  I read multiple other questions on this site that said since its a mutable object i don't need to do Global dict and when i tried that it got an error.  I am able to edit the object but when i go back out of my if statement and for loop it won't carry over.

Please help me :)

```
#This is the inventory in this room
inventory = {'desk': 'Miniature Fusion Warhead',  
         'bed':'knife', 'sink':None}        
def take(item):
    if item in inventory.itervalues():
        #add_item_to_inventory(item)

        for key, value in inventory.iteritems():

            if value == item:
                print ("Wow.\n"
                    "Look at you.\n"
                    "Picking shit up and everything.")
                value = None


    else:
        print ("What do you think this is?"
            "  The dollar store?  We don't "
            "got that shit here!")


# Prints out what items are in the room.  
# I am hoping to later come up with an idea for how
# To make different variations of this, and have it randomly
# pick between the different ways it says what it sees.
for key, value in inventory.iteritems():
    if value != None:
        print "You see a %s on the %s." % (value, key)
print "What do you want to pick up?"
ui = raw_input(">")
split_ui = ui.split()
print split_ui

if len(split_ui) > 1:
    if split_ui[0] == "take":
        print ("You reach over to grab the %s."
            "\n...") % split_ui[1]
    take(split_ui[1])

    else:
        print ("What you talking bout Willis?  "
            "Don't you know this is just about "
            "takin shit.")
else:
    print ("Who taught you how to talk?"
        "\n...\nLet me show you how its done.\n"
        "Use a verb, like take, then throw in an "
        "object like knife.")

print inventory
```

This is the output that I am given.

```
You see a knife on the bed.
You see a Miniature Fusion Warhead on the desk.
What do you want to pick up?
>take knife
['take', 'knife']
You reach over to grab the knife.
...
Wow.
Look at you.
Picking shit up and everything.
{'sink': None, 'bed': 'knife', 'desk': 'Miniature Fusion Warhead'}
```

Important note:  This currently only works if you take the knife and not the Warhead.  I need to figure out another solution for items with multiple words.

Thanks!

Comment: can you please cleanup the syntax of your example code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `value` inside your loop is different than the real value of the dictionary.
It is just a reference to that value, so when you do `value = None` you actually change
the value of the reference to hold the new value `None` and not the value of the dictionary.

To demonstrate it better this is before the assignment inside the `for key, value in inventory.iteritems():`

```
-------            -------------------------
|value|   -------> |value of the dictionary|
-------            -------------------------
```

this is after `value = None`

```
                   -------------------------
                   |value of the dictionary|
                   -------------------------
-------            ------
|value|   -------> |None|
-------            ------
```

As you can see the dictionary value does not change. Only the variable `value` of the `for` loop
changes. This variable belongs to the scope of the `for` loop and after that it is discarded.

An alternative would be instead of `value = None` to do:

```
inventory[key] = None
```

Comment: Or `del inventory[key]`, and when getting from the dictionary, use `inventory.get(key, None)`. That would be a more robust way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help!  This solved my issue.  I was struggling to come up with a way to find the key based on the value and I kind of mashed some other solutions together and it worked so i ran with it.  I had never thought about the fact that I wasn't actually changing the dictionary but rather a variable that i had set to the value of the dictionary.  Your example really helped me understand, thank you for teaching me rather than simply giving me the answer!

Answer (score 1):

zbs is correct, you're only changing the value of the pointer to the dict value. However, you're making this way too hard:

```
#This is the inventory in this room
inventory = {'Miniature Fusion Warhead': 'desk',
             'knife':'bed'}
player_inventory = set()

def take(item):
  if item in inventory:
    print("You picked up the {}".format(item))
    player_inventory.add(item)
    del inventory[item]

  else:
    print("That item doesn't exist")

while True:
  print('')
  print("Inventory: " + ', '.join(player_inventory))
  for k,v in inventory.items():
    print("You see a {} on the {}".format(k, v))

  print("What do you want to pick up?")
  ui = raw_input("> ").split()
  verb = ui[0]
  item = ' '.join(ui[1:])
  if verb == 'take':
    if item:
      print("You take the {}".format(item))
      take(item)
    else:
      print("That item doesn't exist")
  else:
    print("That's not an action")
```